# how to know when a button has been clicked a second time

Tags: c#, button

Hey I have a button called next and when it is clicked the first time it creates a textbox and label but I want to make it  create another textbox when it is clicked the second time and then remove the button.

Comment: Without showing us the code that you tried we cannot help. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add a bool field initialised to false. When the button is clicked, check the flag. If it's true do A() else set the flag to true and do B(). This is pretty basic stuff...

Comment: winforms?  wpf? asp.net? All could be using c#, all with different answers.

Comment: You could have a variable that is outside of the click method, for example `public bool clicked = false;`, then when you click, check if it's true - if not, set it to true - otherwise it's been clicked already

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to SO!

In the code behind you could have a simple flag:

`bool buttonPressed = false`

and then, in the button_click event:

```
if(!buttonPressed)
{
    buttonPressed = true
    // do stuff
}
else
{
    // do other stuff
    // delete the button
}
```

Comment: You don't even know if he is using winforms or wpf or asp.net?

Comment: No, I don't - but I thought I'd give an answer anyway. As long as he's using eventing rather than commands, the concept applies

Comment: The reason why questioners usually doesn't effort to provide enough information.

Comment: Thanks very much it worked... but please how do I add my codes I can't seem to it figure out. Thanks again

Comment: @nky at this point I'm afraid you'll have to provide more information - show us an example of what you've got so far, what have you tried?  Click the "edit" button underneath your question and explain what you need in more detail. It would also help to know if you are using wpf, winforms, asp.net or something else.

Comment: @simonalexander2005 Oh I meant the answer you gave worked for me. I just wanted to know how to add my codes to a question for future purposes. And I'm using windows form

Comment: @nky ok, so yeah, edit your question and you can paste it in. Then highlight it, and use the `{ }` option in the menu at the top to make it show up as code.

Comment: Thanks and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a counter, like every time the click-event is triggered count +1 or you could count the existing textboxes.

And then say: If counter or numberOfTextBoxes >= 2 then hide/remove button.